# How to kill a process using process name in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, kill-process

My requirement is to kill a process. I have the process name.
Below is my code:

```
def kill_process(name):
  os.system(f"TASKKILL /F /IM {name}")
```

It works for Windows but not for Mac. My requirement is that it should work for both the OS.
Is there a way to make the above code OS independent or how can I code it for Mac?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Regards,
Rushikesh Kadam.

Answer (score 8):

[psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) supports a number of platforms (including Windows and Mac).

The following solution should fit the requirement:

```
import psutil

def kill_process(name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == name:
            proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import os, signal

def kill_process(name):
    for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + name + " | grep -v grep"):
        fields = line.split()
        pid = fields[0]
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: `pgrep` and `pkill` are more specialized commands dealing with this than parsing `ps ax` and the OP specifically requested a platform-agnostic solution while this is Linux/macOS.